# Aborting a dialog from within the dialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dialog, abort

There are 2 Forms **FA** and **FB**.
 **FA** is the initial form and it issues **FB.ShowDialog()** to launch **FB**. **FB** starts well, but then encounters a problem and wishes to abort, returning control to **FA**. 
 I thought coding

```
Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
Me.Close()
```

when **FB** hits the problem would do the trick. but no - the code rumbles on, and (presumably a logic error on my part) bumps into the same problem again, and again.
 I will nail the logic problem, but is there no way of actually stopping the form dead - the equivalent of `Me.AbortFormImmediately` ?

Comment: We need to see more relevant code.  What entails "encounters a problem"?

Comment: You just need `Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`. Remove `Me.Close()`.Do you have some code in the `FormClosing` event of that Form? Or something that references the Form's default instance?

Comment: Once you set the `DialogResult` property, the form will close once the stack unwinds. If you don't want to execute any additional code, don't. You can add a `Return` statement immediately after it and the current method will exit there. You can use `If` statements to control what does and doesn't get executed in that or other methods. Basically, it's up to you to structure your code such that nothing else gets executed after that. It won't just happen on its own.

Comment: Thank you, **jmcilhinney** and **jimi**. My mistake was doing a bit of tidying up after setting **DialogResult**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the Comments are great and should help the person asking the question
I am going to expand on this question with the thought that Closing forms happens two ways
Either a BACK button is pressed to go to another form
OR
The TitleBar Close Button (the X) is selected
Because I got tired of writing the code on each form to manage these process
I added a Module to the project and added a Public Sub to do all the work

With a little work this Module Code could be improved upon

Here is the Relevant Code

The Module

```
Module ModuleOne
Public Sub CloseTheForm()
    Const message As String = "YES Go To Form One" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO CANCEL"
    Const caption As String = "EXIT"

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        If frmThree.Visible Then
            frmThree.Hide()
            frmOne.Show()
        End If
        If frmFour.Visible Then
            frmFour.Hide()
            frmOne.Show()
        End If

    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        If frmThree.Visible Then
            frmThree.tbHaveTwo.Text = "CANCEL"
        End If
        If frmFour.Visible Then
            frmFour.tbFive.Text = "CANCEL"
        End If
    End If
End Sub End Module
```

Relevant Code for frmThree

```
    Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    tbHaveOne.Clear()
    CloseTheForm()
End Sub

Public Sub frmThree_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    CloseTheForm()
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Code for frmFour

```
    Public Sub frmFor_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    CloseTheForm()
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    tbFour.Clear()
    CloseTheForm()
End Sub
```